# Work manager class having issue with executing doWork() method

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, android-workmanager, periodic-task, workmanagertaskexecutor

First let me correct please :

**Work Manager : The minimum repeat interval that can be defined is 15 minutes (same as the JobScheduler API).**
If this is not correct please let me know.

I have created below class for executing **periodic** work request :

```
object WorkManagerUtils {

fun syncWorkManager() {
    val myConstraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()

    val syncRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest
            .Builder(MyWorker::class.java, 20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .setConstraints(myConstraints)
            .build()

    WorkManager
            .getInstance()
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                    Constants.WORKER,
                    ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                    syncRequest)
   }
}
```

Below is my Worker class. Please check :

```
class MyWorker(val context: Context, param: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, param) {
override fun doWork(): Result {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
        callSyncApi()
    } else {
        WorkManagerUtils.syncWorkManager()
    }
    return Result.success()
}

private fun callSyncApi() {
        ToastUtils.shortToast(0,"This is working")
   }
 }
```

Calling this in my Activity as below :

```
WorkManagerUtils.syncWorkManager()
```

You can notice that currently I am just displaying toast as my work. I want to check that is this working or not ?

But the toast is not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Any interval under 15 minutes will be replaced by 15 minutes.

Assuming your `ToastUtils.showToast(...)` works, I believe work manager chose 15 minutes of interval and the “KEEP” existing work policy prevented rescheduling and testing.

I suggest while testing change the existing work policy to “REPLACE”.

From work manager 1.0.0 source:

```
public final class PeriodicWorkRequest extends WorkRequest {
    ...
    public static final long MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 15 * 60 * 1000L; // 15 minutes
    ...
}

public class WorkSpec {
    ...
    public void setPeriodic(long intervalDuration) {
        if (intervalDuration < MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS) {
            ...
            IntervalDuration = MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

There is an overload of `setPeriodic` function which applies the same interval enforcement.

Comment: Hello, I have to call a web service for every 10 seconds, It is not possible with Work manager and with Job Scheduler because minimum interval is 15 mins for them. What is the alternative for the same ?

Comment: Your only option is to use alarm manager with foreground service to keep your app alive - keep in mind that if your app is killed (there are evil battery optimizers out there) you need to reschedule.

Comment: Ya I think so, Will you please provide me sample demo link. I am searching it from my side. Thanks sir.

Comment: Android developers: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#examples-of-real-time-clock-alarms